Can you Identify this movie based on the content, I list below?
I recall this movie being in the color format, perhaps produced and released from the mid 80s to the early 90s. 
The plot I can remember, is there were Greek or Roman figurines on a table in a modern day setup home library/study and while the camera focused on these very figurines the story telling began and we were taken back in time to show a partial enactment, and later we come back in time. Please ask more questions. I'm happy to edit this as many times required or add comments. 
One last bit, this movie was airing on free to air channels on TV in USA in 1990 or 1992. 

Done, view this and assist further.

Jason and the Argonauts? It's from the 60s, but you may have not known that when you saw it. In that movie, the Gods are setting events in motion on earth by using something like chess pieces on a board. This trailer doesn't show those scenes, but it might trigger other memories.



There is a very brief moment of it captured in this clip, right at time mark 0:16




A similar trope was used in Clash of the Titans (the original).

Thank you too, Todd Wilcox. Was there anything with the aforementioned context produced in the late 80s to mid 90s? My memory might be clouded, but I recall the greek/roman figurines being viewed in a modern day setup and the story takes us back and forth in time while focusing on those relevant figurines.

@J. Raefield Excellent answer, perfect content, representation, and candor. After watching the full movie, I'm sad to say we need another title. My search revealed 'Aphrodite' from 1982, but this is a soft core erotic themed flick, I doubt such things would play on television.
